# What is the equivalent of ARRAY_AGG(foo where bar) in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I want to do this:

```sql
with source_data as (
   select 1 as id, 'a' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 1 as id, 'b' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 2 as id, 'a' as sub_id, false as turned_on
union all
   select 2 as id, 'b' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 3 as id, 'a' as sub_id, false as turned_on
union all
   select 3 as id, 'b' as sub_id, false as turned_on
)

select
  id,
  array_agg(sub_id where turned_on) as all_on,    -- invalid syntax
  turned_off(sub_id where turned_off) as all_off  -- invalid syntax
from
  source_data
group by id
```

to get something like

```
| id  | all_on | all_off |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | [a, b] |         |
| 2   | [b]    | [a]     |
| 3   |        | [a, b]  |
```

the marked rows are invalid, because I can't do `ARRAY_AGG(... where ...)`. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) I gather I could probably accomplish something similar using analytic functions (particularly `PARTITION BY`) but I don't understand how.

Is it possible to write a query that aggregates arrays the way I illustrate above? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `if`:

```
with source_data as (
   select 1 as id, 'a' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 1 as id, 'b' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 2 as id, 'a' as sub_id, false as turned_on
union all
   select 2 as id, 'b' as sub_id, true as turned_on
union all
   select 3 as id, 'a' as sub_id, false as turned_on
union all
   select 3 as id, 'b' as sub_id, false as turned_on
)
select
  id,
  array_agg(if(turned_on=true, sub_id, null) ignore nulls) as all_on,
  array_agg(if(turned_on=false, sub_id, null) ignore nulls) as all_off
from
  source_data
group by id
```